# How to rerender a div in template xhtml page

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a problem with rendering a page with userdata.

There is a template .xhtml whitch looks like this:

```
<h:body>
    <div id="page">

        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
        </div>          
        <div id="right_area">
            <ui:insert name="right_area">
                <ui:include src="../../user/showUser.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

The showUser.xhtml shows some user data i would like to update

In the content div i have a form with a commandbutton to update the data

```
<h:commandButton type="submit"
id="update" 
action="#{Bean.updateData}"
reRender="right_area">
</h:commandButton>
```

After i clicked the button the database is updated but the "right_area" does not rerender.
I also tried:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit"
id="update" 
action="#{Bean.updateData}">
<a4j:ajax execute="update" render="right_area"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I get no error messages
Any help pointing in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: have you tried @BalusC solution but using `a4j:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a fullworthy JSF component instead of a plain vanilla HTML element if you ever want to re-render it by JSF. You can use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` to render a `<div>`.

Also, your client ID is interpreted relative to the current naming container (which is `<h:form>` in your case). It is looking for a component with `id="right_area"` inside the context of the `<h:form>`, but it does not exist. You need to specify an absolute ID instead, starting with the default naming container separator character `:`, thus so `render=":right_area"`.

Finally, the `<h:commandButton>` doesn't have a `reRender` attribute, you're confusing with old RichFaces 3.x's `<a4j:commandButton>`. You should be using `<a4j:commandButton render>`, or `<f:ajax render>` or `<a4j:ajax render>` instead.

So, summarized

```
<h:panelGroup id="right_area" layout="block">
    <ui:insert name="right_area">
        <ui:include src="../../user/showUser.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <a4j:ajax execute="update" render=":right_area"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

should do.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer BalusC. I tried your ideas but the problem is still the same. Evan the attempt to render the whole page with `<h:panelGroup id="page" layout="block">` & `<a4j:ajax execute="update" render=":page"/>` didn't work. Do you have any other ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that the button's action is really invoked, then this can only mean that you've apparently other naming container components in your real code which weren't visible in your question. Rightclick page in browser, *View Source*, locate the generated HTML `<div>` element and use the value of its `id` attribute. That's the real client ID.